# Unable to redirect the URL to another page in docker app

Tags: node.js, docker, mern

Summarize of my problem:

I have create a website using MERN stack and deployed to AWS using docker.

1. when I refresh the domain page i.e http://discussion.sramanujan.com/ ,it works fine.
2. When I directly try to access the discussion url http://discussion.sramanujan.com/discussion , I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Steps to repro the issue:

1. lauch the website http://discussion.sramanujan.com/
2. Refresh the browser [website should reload successfully]
3. Click on discussion button.  [website url will change to http://discussion.sramanujan.com/discussion ]
4. Refresh the page.

Expected:
Page should load discussion page on refresh

Actual:
Got an error message as "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Any idea as how to handle this issue?

More information:

1.host server port 80 is mapped to docker container port 3000.

2.Navigation through website is working fine.

3. /usr/src/api is my WORKDIR

Logs from server:(on refresh I get error 500)
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the logs? I'm sure express is dumping some output to logs regarding details of the error.

Comment: in the browser I can see error message as " the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". And I am new to docker and AWS, not sure how can I check logs in AWS server(if this is something I should post it here).

Comment: Have you tried running it locally? Could be much easier to debug. You should see the logs by running it with arguments `-it` locally (see Docker TTY mode) or if you're using `docker-compose` then it will show you right out of the box.

Comment: I have added, a screenshot of the error logged at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

you are also getting a 304 (Not modified) error on your website, try to enable javaScript, after that it should work

Comment: Javascript is turned on in my browser.